# Require dynamic path synchronously

Tags: webpack

I want to require a file. Its path is in some config:

```
//config.js
module.exports = "/home/css/style.css";

//entry.js
var path = require(./config.js);
require("style!css!" + path);

Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "."
```

How can I require files with path that can take root `/` directory?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use `require.ensure`
For ex.:

```
function handleRouteChange(path) {
    require(['/views/' + path], function(PageView) {
        app.setView(new PageView());
    });
}
```

changes to:

```
function loadPage(PageView) {
    app.setView(new PageView());
}
function handleRouteChange(path) {
    switch (path) {
        case 'settings':
            require(['/views/settings'], loadPage);
            break;
        case 'transfer':
            require(['/views/transfer'], loadPage);
            break;
        case 'wallet':
            require(['/views/wallet'], loadPage);
            break;
    default:
        // you could either require everything here as a last resort or just leave it...
    }
}
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/xjamundx/b1c800e9282e16a6a18e#the-routing-code-old-and-new

Comment: I want to set absolute path in my Linux system, it will be too much for webpack to pass the whole system through some loader (style and css in my example)

Comment: You mean to say some context in which webpack can take your root directory?

Comment: Yes. Maybe some there is some plugin that allows do it.